# Building an OpenStack cloud: where do I install the maas and openstack packages?

Tags: maas, openstack, cloud, landscape, openstack-autopilot

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/cloud/install-ubuntu-openstack

The instructions don't tell me where the packages need to be installed. Do these packages need to be installed on every node? I have multiple nodes to work with.

Answer (score 1):

MAAS will be on its own node, and most people usually run the installer from the MAAS machine. You'll still need 7 machines as stated in the requirements section from that document.